# Build REST API Endpoint with Angular

Tags: angular, rest

Let's say we have an Angular web app that lists patients, the route would be something like `http://localhost:4200/patients`.

Is there a way to deliver the same content (from the exact same data source) in JSON format (application/json) by calling `http://localhost:4200/server/api/patients`, for example?

In other words, I'd like to build a REST API endpoint with Angular.

**EDIT:** My goal is to provide a means for external systems to access real data in production environments.

Comment: You can use in memory web api. https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: Your question in unclear : do you want to deliver real data ? Do you want to mock your data ? Do you want to use it in production or is it just for testing ? Please identify your use case and what you're expecting.

Comment: @trichetriche: See edit above.

Comment: Angular is primarily for Front End User Interface. There are many other technologies that lets you achieve your objective (For REST API End point creation) example. .Net Core. If you intende to do with scripting then go for Node.JS.

Comment: I wrote a way to do it - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/angular-universal-rest-api-endpoints-23fj

Answer (score 1):

Angular apps normally run entirely in the browser.  Since nothing is running on a server, it's not possible to use it for a web api.

However, I came across this question while implementing a small Angular Universal app with server-side rendering.  In this case, an Express server does the SSR and I wanted it to also handle some api calls.

The server.ts file (autogenerated when adding @nguniversal/express-engine) includes a commented-out section showing how to do it.

```
  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
```

For testing, replace it with something like

```
  server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { res.send('Hello!') });
```

You can hit it from the browser with `http://localhost:4200/api/test`, or from the angular app with `this.http.get('api/test')`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prepend some string like 'server/api/', you can use the environtment to do that.

is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

This not possible because the Root component  and sub component in angular is rendered using view templet which is html finally ,
 Angular is javascript MVC Framework . So ultimately every data angular gets by making Web Service Api call should be populated into some component . So ultimately the mime type you will be getting back from angular is text/html .

**Angular is not build for developing Rest Api** . You can use Node.js for this purpose if you want to code only in javascript.

follow this link to know frameworks available in node.js for this purpose

[Node js Rest Api frameworks](http://nodeframework.com/index.html#rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Following your edit :

Yes you can. This is available in production mode, when you serve your application.

This isn't an Angular issue but a server issue : your server must

1. Serve the built Angular application
2. Serve the REST API.

This highly depends on your server, so you should make a new question with your server as tags, and ask how to set it up to serve several applications at once.

And I must state it because a lot of people don't get it, but **Angular isn't made to create REST APIs**. You will build your API with anything else you want (and that can do it), you will just serve it on the same domain.